# How to rename files in all directories in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that rename all the files from .txt to .txt2.
I want to do the same thing but in all the subdirectories.

This is my code.

```
rename 's/.txt/.txt2' *.txt
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the answer, but it's hardly readable.

`````bash
for filePath in $(find . -name "*.txt"); do filePathWithoutExtension=$(echo ${filePath} | head -c -4) && mv ${filePath} ${filePathWithoutExtension}txt2; done
```

Before :
````bash
tree
.
├── folder1
│   ├── foo.txt
│   ├── subfolder1
│   │   └── foo.txt
│   └── subfolder2
│       └── foo.txt
├── folder2
│   └── foo.txt
└── foo.txt

4 directories, 5 files
`````

After :

```bash
tree
.
├── folder1
│   ├── foo.txt2
│   ├── subfolder1
│   │   └── foo.txt2
│   └── subfolder2
│       └── foo.txt2
├── folder2
│   └── foo.txt2
└── foo.txt2

4 directories, 5 files
```

Comment: This is bad code. Don't handle files with spaces or other special characters, and variables non properly quoted. **Don't use this!** Asked you `ChatGPT` to create this horrible snippet? It's works here, because you have simple files, but in `RealLife©®™`  it will break

Answer (score 0):

Like this using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

```
shopt -s globstar # bash specific, enabled by default in `zsh`
rename 's/\.txt$/\.txt2/' ./**/*.txt
```

Comment: Anything wrong with this valid answer @agm_2502?